# Move 2 matchsticks to make the equation correct, and give 3 ways to do so

Tags: matches

I am trying to solve the following matchsticks puzzle:

> Move two matches to make the following correct: [image] You also have to give 3 ways to do so.

Despite trying my best to solve this, I wasn't able to give 3 ways to do so. I could only think of one. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Source: 450 multiple intelligence games that Harvard made for students puzzle book(translated, original title(in Chinese): 哈佛给学生做的450个多元智能顺练游戏)

Comment: While I have answered this puzzle below, it would be good if you could provide the source where you found it so that the original content creator is credited. Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv, to be honest, I really do not know who created this puzzle. I actually found it inside a Chinese puzzle book that comes from Taiwan called "450 multiple intelligence games made by Harvard for students"(the Google translation of the title). I also didn't buy it, someone gave it to me. The original title of the book(in Chinese) is "哈佛给学生做的450个多元智能顺练游戏"

Comment: Okay, maybe just mention that in the question itself following "Source:" - all non-original puzzles posted on PSE should be credited somehow, so we can avoid any messy accusations of plagiarism. I think that would probably be sufficient :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this puzzle as follows:

> [image]

...producing the equations:

> $$1 + 9 - 2 = 8$$
>  $$1 + 9 - 8 = 2$$
>  $$1 + 5 + 0 = 6$$

Comment: The second solution is incredibly straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

Three more (variations on a single theme):

> [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

> move the 2 vertical matches from 5 to turn 5 into a 2. and you get $1 + 9 - 8 = 2$

Solution 2:

> remove 1 match from 9 to make it a 5 and remove the center match from 8. Add them as follows. 1 add it over the minus to make it a plus. one add it vertically to the 5 after the equal sign to make it a 6. You get $1 + 5 + 0 = 6$

Solution 3:

> take 2 matched from the 8 transforming it to 2. Move the matches to the 5 making it an 8. You get $1 + 9 - 2 = 8$

Answer (score 3):

Here are three more solutions different to the ones given already

Solution 1

> *Remove* two matches like so
>  [image]
>  Then flip your screen upside down
>  [image]

Solution 2

> Remove one match and move one match like so
>  [image]
>  Then flip your screen upside down
>  [image]

Solution 3

> Move two matches like so
>  [image]
>  Then flip your screen upside down
>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

All the obvious answers have been posted so here's a less orthodox one:

> [image: 1+9-8<5]

Comment: This is not an equation.

Comment: @Marius The puzzle says "make the equation correct". Not "make the equation a correct equation." This is correct.

Comment: exactly...and `a<b` is not an equation. it's an [inequation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation). So your answer is not correct. I'm not saying the inequation is not correct...the answer is not.

Comment: @Marius Where did I say a<b was an equation?

Comment: @Marius If you're trying to argue that my technically correct answer isn't wholly in line with the spirit of the rules, scroll up and check which site we're on.

Comment: @Marius I agree with Studoku’s reasoning. I would add that the word “equation” does not even appear in the body of the question – it says “make the following correct”.

Comment: the title says "Move 2 matchsticks to make the **equation** correct, and give 3 ways to do so". But let's say you are right and stop this discussion, because it's not helping anyone.

Comment: @Marius I will concede that this lateral thinking uses the literal rather than the intended wording but isn't that half the fun here?

Comment: We in general only accept [lateral-thinking] answers to questions tagged with [lateral-thinking]. Since this question is not, answers should strive to be in the spirit of the question

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be at least 5 different ways to make it correct. Here are the 3 ways I found:

> 1 + 9 - 8 = 2
>  1 + 8 - 6 = 3
>  1 + 8 - 3 = 6